# Where does "restroom" come from?

Tags: etymology

Where does the term "restroom" come from?  It surely can't have anything to do with *resting*.

The first time I landed at a US airport I was actually so confused about this that I thought that the "Restroom →" signs were showing the way to the waiting hall.

Comment: Have you tried to [Google it](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=origin%20of%20restroom)? What does it say and what is it that you don't understand?

Comment: Why can't it have anything to do with resting?  People often do sit down there, even if the primary purpose is not to rest. It's just a euphemism.

Comment: I was really expecting that "rest" would have a different meaning here, perhaps one unknown to me.

Comment: You don’t have kids do you? ;-)

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/restroom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[Restroom](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/2870/why-is-it-called-a-restroom-anyway):***

> - Of course no one wants to rest in the room containing the toilet; ***restroom is an obvious euphemism.*** Interestingly, English (like some other languages) can express the "toilet-room" concept only via indirect terms like this.

Restroom:

> - ***Originally meaning a public toilet, this seems to be of American origin, with the earliest usages found around 1900***. It’s an extremely common usage, and also one of the vaguest. Rest of course has a number of meanings, but this is probably in the sense of "repose" or "refreshing oneself." A slight variation is retiring room, a lovely upper-class Briticism from the 1930s.

From  [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=restroom):

> - also rest-room, ***1897, as a room with a toilet***, from rest (n.1) + room. (n.).

Comment: Funnily enough there isn't a word for it that isn't a euphemism.

Comment: @mgb, you consider "the shitter" a euphemism?

Comment: @ThePhoton - I hadn't allowed for Australians